# Can't import dataset on RStudio

Tags: statistics

I can't import datasets on RStudio on either my computer or Posit Cloud. I think it's because my laptop is too old to install packages necessary to import datasets on it, and not sure for Posit Cloud. Someone else imported it for me in a lab so I know it's possible, but when I try myself it seems like it only let me import things from their Cloud rather than from my computer.